# including dummy variable in SEM

Tags: categorical-data, structural-equation-modeling

Let us consider a regression model
$y_i = \alpha+\beta x_i + \gamma d_i + u_i$ where $y_i$ and $x_i$ are scalar continuous variables and $d_i$ is a dummy variable that takes 0 or 1. (this is just a toy model; the model I'm considering is more complicated)

I want to estimate a kind of the above model with longitudinal data where dummy variables are included in addition to the continuous variables by using structural equation modeling(covariance structure analysis).

If $d_i$ is absent, I know how to estimate by ML or GLS. But, if dummy variable $d_i$ is included, I don't know how to estimate $\gamma$.

Is it possible to estimate such a model by ML? Do we need to consider multiple group SEM?

Any comments are appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that d_i is missing? I don't see how multiple group solves this - how do you know what group to assign that unit to?

Comment: I'm assuming that $d_i$ is observed dummy variable such as male/female or having a car or not.

Comment: Ah, I see. (I think). You don't treat it any differently from any other variable - just as in regression.